# How to cast one compound custom type to another

Tags: c#

I'm trying to write a converter class for custom types--converting one type (and all of its properties) to another type that has matching properties.

The problem comes in when the property is also a custom type, rather that a simple type.
The custom types are all identical, except they live in different namespaces in the same solution.
TypeTwo objects are Webservice references.

For example

```
public TypeOne ConvertToTypeTwo (TypeTwo typeTwo)
{
var typeOne = new TypeOne();
typeOne.property1 = typeTwo.property1; //no problem on simple types
typeOne.SubType = typeTwo.SubType; //problem!
...
}
```

The error I get on the line above is:

> Error 166 Cannot implicitly convert type 'TypeTwo.SubType' to 'TypeOne.SubType'

I've tried casting like so

```
typeOne.SubType = (TypeOne)typeTwo.SubType;
```

But get:

> Error 167 Cannot convert type 'TypeTwo.SubType' to 'TypeOne.SubType'

And like so

```
typeOne.SubType = typeTwo.SubType as TypeOne;
```

But get:

> Error 168 Cannot convert type 'TypeTwo.SubType' to 'TypeOne.SubType' via a reference
>   conversion, boxing conversion, unboxing conversion, wrapping
>   conversion, or null type conversion

I'm not sure what other options I have, or if I'm just doing something fundamentally wrong.
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do that. Even if the two types have *exactly* the same layout (same fields with same types), you *cannot* **cast** from one to another. It's impossible.

What you have to do instead is to create a converter (either as method, a separate class or a cast operator) that can translate from a type to another.

Comment: Thanks.  Your advice did the trick.  I wrote a separate converter for the subtypes and then just call that method instead of trying the impossible cast.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 7):

If the two subtypes are different types, you'll have to write a separate converter to convert between the two types.

For example:

```
public TypeOne ConvertToTypeTwo (TypeTwo typeTwo)
{
    var typeOne = new TypeOne();
    typeOne.property1 = typeTwo.property1; //no problem on simple types
    typeOne.SubType = ConvertToTypeTwo(typeTwo.SubType); //problem!
}

public TypeOneSubtype ConvertToTypeTwo(TypeTwoSubType typeTwo)
{
    var subOne = new TypeOneSubType;
    subOne.property1 = typeTwo.property1;
    // etc.
}
```